# Python idiom for creating a given number of elements in a list

Tags: python, list-comprehension, python-itertools

Often when I'm using Python I'll find myself writing list comprehensions that look something like this:

```
num_foobars = 10
foobars = [create_foobar() for idx in xrange(num_foobars)]
```

Obviously that works just fine, but it still feels a little awkward to me to creating a range and iterating dummy index across it, when I'm not actually using that information at all.

I'm not in any way concerned about performance or anything like that, it just doesn't feel quite as wonderfully elegant as Python usually does.

I'm wondering if there's any nice idiomatic way to avoid the unnecessary bits of list comprehension syntax, perhaps using something like `map` or something in `itertools`, to give me code that looks more like...

```
num_foobars = 10
foobars = repeat(create_foobar, num_foobars)
```

Comment: isn't repeat do exactly what you want ?

Comment: @AviramSegal: No, because it doesn't call the function n times. It just returns the function object n times.

Comment: i ment repeat(create_foobar(), num_foobars), or do you need to call the function every time ?

Comment: @AviramSegal: Obviously - that's what his initial code is doing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the itertools way:

```
list(starmap(create_foobar, repeat((), 10)))
```

The itertools way is short and fast.  That said, I prefer the list comprehension :-)

Answer (score 1):

In cases where `create_foobar` accepts an argument, it's just a matter of iterating over a list of arguments. As in

```
[create_foobar(x) for x in arg_list]
```

or

```
[create_foobar(*x) for x in [arg_tuple] * 10]
```

But in the special case that `create_foobar` takes no arguments, I suppose you could do something like this:

```
>>> class Foobar(object):
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.a = random.randrange(0, 10)
...     def __repr__(self):
...         return str(self.a)
... 
>>> map(lambda x: x(), [Foobar] * 10)
[2, 5, 3, 4, 7, 4, 6, 3, 3, 6]
```

The lambda is a bit ugly though; echoing [Raymond Hettinger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8911769/577088)'s sentiments, I think the standard list comprehension is preferable. It's also worth noting that this creates a rather long and useless list to iterate over, which the standard approach avoids. You could fix that by using `itertools.repeat` to create an iterable of `Foobar`s... adding even more complication.

```
>>> map(lambda x: x(), itertools.repeat(Foobar, 10))
[1, 4, 4, 6, 2, 4, 9, 9, 1, 6]
```

More generally, consider this: if you aren't iterating *over* anything, there has to be an index variable, even if it's hidden; and explicit is better than implicit.

Answer (score 0):

You could define the function `repeat`, but the idiomatic way to write it would still be

```
def repeat(f, max_n):
    return [f(i) for i in xrange(max_n)]
```

Sorry about that. I agree that `xrange`-based constructs often look ugly, but it's just how the language works.

Answer (score -1):

```
def repeat(creator, num):
    return [create() for x in xrange(num)]
```

;c)